# Javascript SyntaxError: redeclaration of class

Tags: javascript, html

I have defined some classes in a remote js file, let's call `remote.js`. The classes follow these patterns.

```
class A {
   constructor() {
   }
}

class B {
   constructor() {
   }
}

class C {
   constructor() {
   }
}
```

In the html file, I have imported the `remote.js` and used them in inline js. However, in some pages, I am getting different errors in different browsers for different classes. All browsers point out that I have redeclared some class more than once.
In Chrome:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'A' has already been declared
    at remote.js` 
In Safari:
`SyntaxError: Can't create duplicate variable: 'B'`
In Firefox: `SyntaxError: redeclaration of let C`
Notice that each browser is pointing at different classes which are not even used in that page. I have not noticed any misbehaviour in these pages yet! I also have checked the contents of the file in `jslint` and it doesn't have any major issue.

Comment: `remote.js` is loaded once?

Comment: Yes it is only loaded once.

Comment: while declaring in inline js, did you use let or const, or did you use var? maybe it's a scope-related problem

Comment: @Harvey I used var.

Comment: Please include the relevant code, see [mcve].

Comment: @KévinBibollet Guesed right, one of the pages in my project was loading the `remote.js` twice